# The subjects of 言わないと分からない in this monologue

Tags: meaning

From what I understand, 言わないと分からない is normally used to say something like "I   can't understand unless you tell me"

Context: The two meet after he has had his bath on the way back to his room.

> 「いえ、ぼんやりしてる様子でお疲れなのかと……」
>
> 「疲れてはないんだ……」
>
> 「もしかして、少しのぼせちゃいましたか？」
>
> 心配してくれるエイルさんに胸が痛む。
>
> 聞いても……いいんだろうか。
>
> そう思ったら、口が開いていた。
>
> 「エイルさんのこと、考えてたんだ」
>
> 「えっ……？」
>
> 「今朝、いつもと違ってたし……元気なさそうだった」
>
> 「なにか悪いことしちゃったかなって……」
>
> こんなこと言っちゃうなんて……情けない。
>
> でも……言わないと分からないことだ。
> 「ネロさん……」
> 「なにか良くないことがあったら、すぐに言ってください。俺からは……それだけです」

But I'm not quite sure what he means by this last sentence. What I believe he's referring back to こんなこと and saying that if he doesn't say what he said above, then....

And here's where my problem comes in. Who is it that won't know/understand and what is it that they won't understand. Looking at it, I think it's something like "But if I don't say these things (Showing that he's worried about her and indirectly asking her if he's done anything wrong), then I won't find out what the problem is". Can anyone clarify what it is that he's actually saying?

Comment: The passage is confusing. It is not clear who says 「なにか悪いことしちゃったかなって……」. I suppose that is the reason why you are not sure.

Comment: The person who said that was the same person who thought to themselves こんなこと言っちゃうなんて……情けない。でも……言わないと分からないことだ

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, エイル says 「いえ、ぼんやりしてる様子でお疲れなのかと……」, 「もしかして、少しのぼせちゃいましたか？」 and 「えっ……？」. The other one says 「疲れてはないんだ……」, 「エイルさんのこと、考えてたんだ」 and 「今朝、いつもと違ってたし……元気なさそうだった」. Then comes 「なにか悪いことしちゃったかなって……」. If the two speak in an alternating fashion, this should belong to エイル but then the story line gets confusing. So, it may be natural to assume this is said by the other one. In that case, こんなこと refers to「なにか悪いことしちゃったかなって……」(= I may have done something bad (to you)).

Comment: I agree, but I still don't understand what he means by 言わないと分からない. Does he mean that if she doesn't say whether he has done something bad, then he won't know whether he has. Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Provided my assumption in my previous comment is correct, I guess the subject of 言わない is the other one (boy?), and that of 分からない is エイル. Thus 言わないと分からない = "she would not understand unless I tell her". This is my best effort in parsing the passage.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but to me it makes more sense that he's saying that he won't know if there's anything wrong unless she tells him. Otherwise  if it was what you said, then I would have no idea what it is that she would not understand.

Comment: Well, you may be right .(There is another possibility that both of us are wrong, but I don't want to think of such extremity.)  Anyway, the writing style of the authour is the problem. It is too obscure and ambiguous. なにか良くないことがあったら、すぐに言ってください。俺からは……それだけです = "If there is a problem, tell me immediately. That's ... all I want to tell you."  is too cryptic for me.

Comment: Whilst I'm not the most confident, and I'm just guessing. Could the line こんなこと言っちゃうなんて……情けない。Be him describing his next line where he says "言わないと分からない". He is saying that whilst saying it is "pathetic", he won't know what's wrong unless she tells him. I'm not that confident though.

Answer (score 0):

誰の発言か分かりにくいようでしたので、誰のセリフかを書き加えてみました。
状況の説明も少し書き足してみました。

エイルに何か悪いことをしてしまったのでは、と少し落ち込むネロ。

エイルは、ネロのことが心配なようだ。

> エイル:「いえ、ぼんやりしてる様子でお疲れなのかと……」
>
> ネロ: 「疲れてはないんだ……」
>
> エイル:「もしかして、少しのぼせちゃいましたか？」
>
> ネロ: 心配してくれるエイルさんに胸が痛む。
>
> ネロ: (何か悪いことをしてしまったか) 聞いても……いいんだろうか。
>
> ネロ: そう思ったら、口が開いていた。
>
> ネロ: 「エイルさんのこと、考えてたんだ」
>
> エイル:「えっ……？」
>
> ネロ: 「今朝、いつもと違ってたし……元気なさそうだった」
>
> ネロ: 「なにか悪いことしちゃったかなって……」
>
> ネロ: こんなこと言っちゃうなんて……情けない。(なにか悪いことしちゃったかな、と聞いてしまうなんて、情けない。)
>
> ネロ: でも……言わないと(エイルに聞かないと)分からないことだ。
>
> エイル:「ネロさん……」
>
> ネロ: 「なにか良くないことがあったら、すぐに言ってください。俺からは……それだけです」

---

「こんなこと」は、「エイルさんのこと、考えてたんだ」 から 「なにか悪いことしちゃったかなって……」 までの発言全体を指していると思います。

「でも……言わないと」も、「こんなこと」と同じものを指しています。

---

> 言わないと分からない is normally used to say something like "I can't understand unless you tell me"

"She is misunderstanding. I should tell her what I think." may be more suitable for this situation.

---

(Tranlated)

> Nero: "I'm thinking about you, Eile"
>
> N: "You seems different .. this morning."
>
> N: "Have I done something bad for you?"
>
> It's a... shame to ask her what I was wrong, but if I don't ask her, I cannot get.

...